# Checkbox Values Missing after upgrading to Sitefinity 6.1

Tags: asp.net, telerik, sitefinity

On our website, we have a page with a set of checkbox lists (http://www.boxerproperty.com/search-results?type=0&mkt=Denver&size=-1&prop=0&page=1).  Each checkbox list is inside a RadDockLayout control:

```
<telerik:RadDockLayout runat="server" ID="RadDockLayout1">
  <telerik:RadDockZone runat="server" ID="RadDockZone1">
    <telerik:RadDock ID="dockSubMarket" Title="SUBMARKETS" runat="server" DefaultCommands="ExpandCollapse" DockMode="Docked" EnableDrag="false">
      <TitlebarTemplate>
        <div class="RadDockTitle">
          SUBMARKETS
        </div>
      </TitlebarTemplate>
      <ContentTemplate>
        <div id="Div5">
          <div id="Div6">
            <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkSubmarket" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Enabled"></asp:CheckBoxList>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ContentTemplate>
    </telerik:RadDock>
  </telerik:RadDockZone>
</telerik:RadDockLayout>
```

Before we upgraded to Sitefinity 6.1, the page markup included the numeric values for the checkboxes:
`<input id="ctl00_cphBreadcrumb_C002_dockSubMarket_C_chkSubmarket_1" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$cphBreadcrumb$C002$dockSubMarket$C$chkSubmarket$1" value="77" />`  (Note the value="77" at the end)

After the upgrade, the value is missing.  How can we get the value back?

Answer (score 1):

The upgrade process from Sitefinity 5.1 to 6.1 added `controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5"` to the pages section in web.config.  That was causing checkboxes to not include the value attribute.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5">
    </pages>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```